# Error use of uninitialized value although it is initialized

Tags: perl

I am trying to make a table looking content of one input file but it constantly gives me an error

```
Use of uninitialized value $ac[3] in concatenation (.) or string at table.pl
    line 58 (#1)
```

and

```
Use of uninitialized value $or[2] in concatenation (.) or string at table.pl
    line 61 (#1)
```

and although I made almost every possible changes it still gives me an error and does not print well.

This is how my input file looks like:

```
HEADER    OXIDOREDUCTASE                          08-JUN-12   2LU5              
EXPDTA    SOLID-STATE NMR                                                       
REMARK   2 RESOLUTION. NOT APPLICABLE.                                          
HETNAM     CU COPPER (II) ION 
HETNAM     ZN ZINC                                              
FORMUL   2   CU    CU 2+
FORMUL   2   ZN    ZN 2+                                                        
END
```

This is a script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#my $testfile=shift;
open(INPUT, "$ARGV[0]") or die 'Cannot make it';
my @file=<INPUT>;
close INPUT;
my @ac=();
my @dr=();
my @os=();
my @or=();
my @fo=();

for (my $line=0;$line<=$#file;$line++)
{
    chomp($file[$line]);
    if ($file[$line] =~ /^HEADER/)
    {
        print( (split '\s+', $file[$line])[-1]);
        print "\t";

        while ($file[$line] !~ /^END /)
        {
            $line++;
            if ($file[$line]=~/^EXPDTA/)
            {
                $file[$line]=~s/^EXPDTA//;
                @os=(@os,split '\s+', $file[$line]);
            }
            if ($file[$line] =~ /^REMARK   2 RESOLUTION./)
            {
                $file[$line]=~s/^REMARK   2 RESOLUTION.//;
                @ac = (@ac,split'\s+',$file[$line]);
            }
            if ($file[$line] =~ /^HETNAM/)
            {
                $file[$line]=~s/^HETNAM//;
                $file[$line] =~ s/\s+//;
                push @dr, $file[$line];
            }
            if ($file[$line] =~ /^SOURCE   2 ORGANISM_SCIENTIFIC/)
            {
                $file[$line]=~s/^SOURCE   2 ORGANISM_SCIENTIFIC//;
                @or = (@or,split'\s+',$file[$line]);
            }
            if ($file[$line] =~ /^FORMUL/)
            {
                $file[$line]=~s/^FORMUL//;
                $file[$line] =~ s/\s+//;
                push @fo, $file[$line];
            }
        }
        print "$os[1] $os[2]\t";
        print "\t";
        @os=();
        print "$ac[3] $ac[4]\t" or die "Cannot be printed"; #line 58
        print "\t";
        @ac=();
        print "$or[2] $or[3]\t" or die "Cannot be printed";  #line 61
        print "\t";
        @or=();
        foreach (@dr)
        {
            print "$_";
            print "\t\t\t\t\t";
        }
        @dr=();
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

And this is the output it gives me, but it doesnt seems to print well and I am really not sure why:

```
2LU5    SOLID-STATE NMR                     CU COPPER (II) ION
```

Desired output that I am expecting is :

```
HEADER                       EXPDTA               REMARK                         HETNAM                                                                                                       FORMUL
OXIDOREDUCTASE  2LU5         SOLID-STATE NMR      RESOLUTION. NOT APPLICABLE.    COPPER (II) ION (here better to say last column because certain diversity exists before "copper")             CU 2+
                                                                                 ZN ZINC                                                       ZN 2+
```

Comment: So perl arrays are 0-based, you might want to try to decrement your indices by one.  `@or` doesn't get filled because you don't have any matching lines that start with `SOURCE....`. `@ac` gets filled with `('NOT', 'APPLICABLE.')`, so `$ac[0]` and `$ac[1]` only have values.

Comment: You probably also need to escape the `/` in your substitution, i.e. `s/foo\//bar/;` or just use a different delimiter: `s|foo/|bar|;`

Comment: What's your actual desired output?

Answer (score 1):

The root of your error is that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @ac = ();

my $str = "REMARK   2 RESOLUTION. NOT APPLICABLE.   ";
$str =~ s/^REMARK   2 RESOLUTION.//;
@ac = ( @ac, split '\s+', $str );
print Dumper \@ac;
```

The contents of `@ac` is:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '',
          'NOT',
          'APPLICABLE.'
        ];
```

There is no `$ac[3]`, you only have elements 0,1,2 in there.

With your `@or` error, you don't have any lines matching: `/^SOURCE   2 ORGANISM_SCIENTIFIC/`

So that array is empty, and that too, means you've got no `$or[2]` to print.

More generally - what you're doing here is actually really quite clunky, and there's a much cleaner solution.

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#set the text "END" as our record separator
local $/ = 'END';

#define the fields to print out. 
my @field_order = qw ( HEADER EXPDTA REMARK HETNAM FORMUL ); 

print join ( ",", @field_order), "\n"; #print header row

#iterate STDIN or file named on command line.
#just like you're doing with open (FILE, $ARGV[0]) 
while ( <> ) {
   #select key value pairs into a hash - first word on the line is the 'key'
   #and the value is 'anything else'. 
   my %this_entry = m/^(\w+)\s+(.*)$/gm;
   next unless $this_entry{'HEADER'}; #check we have a header.

   s/\s+/ /g for values %this_entry; #strip repeated spaces from fields; 
   s/\s+$//g for values %this_entry; #strip trailing whitespace. 

   #split 'header' row into separate subfields
   #this is an example of how you could transform other fields. 
   ($this_entry{'HEADER'}, $this_entry{'DATE'}, $this_entry{'STRUCT'} ) = split ' ', $this_entry{'HEADER'};


   print join (",", @this_entry{@field_order} ), "\n";
}
```

This will - given your input - print:

```
HEADER,DATE,STRUCT,EXPDTA,REMARK,HETNAM,FORMUL
OXIDOREDUCTASE,08-JUN-12,2LU5,SOLID-STATE NMR,2 RESOLUTION. NOT APPLICABLE.,CU COPPER (II) ION,2 CU CU 2+
```

Which isn't quite what your output matches, but hopefully it's illustrated how much simpler this task could be?

Comment: If you ask another question with desired input/output formats, I'm happy enough to rework the solution I've posted to be more exact.

Comment: @Sorbique I am very sorry for my late response but wasn't available during the last three weeks. Yees, the code of yours looks extremely efficient and simple..wish I could reach half of that level of programming one day :) I will edit the question so I can include what is the desired output. The main thing is that I want all rows from the input (except `END`) to put as a columns in output and seperate them by tab. Each column will be followed by rows that are remainings or extension of each row from an input..It is a bit harder to explain so I will edit a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Sorbique one more thing that may play role is that my real input file is big and it is multiplication of input file from example, so just imagine input file from example `*90 000`. And, not that there can be more `HET` and `FORMUL` lines so in that case I would like only one title for example `HET` or `FORMUL` that should be followed by all lines..Ill edit it as well

Comment: If it's hard to explain, it's probably worth another question.

Comment: @Sorbique But thats why I have edited it so it can be easier to understand :)